# Dont get value of text area that have tinymce editor

Tags: java, tinymce, wicket-1.4

```
TextArea val=new TextArea<String>("notes",new PropertyModel<String>(this,"notesData"));
val.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

but I am not able to get value of TextArea onsubmit method of `ajaxButton("id",form);`

I need the value of text area in java code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').getContent();`